# Error a la hora de ejecutar en localhost

Tags: angularjs

Estoy tratando de hacer una mini aplicacion en angular pero me da error a la hora de ejecutarlo.

Mi controlador:

```
var app = angular.module("pacientesApp",[]);
//controller
app.controller("controladorPacientes", function controllerPacientes($scope, $http){
    $http.get("../pacientesJSON.php").success(function(r){
        $scope.pacientes = r.pacientes;
    });
});
```

Esto llama a un php:

```
<?php
$usuario ="root";
$pwd = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$db = "loquesea";
$link = mysql_pconnect($servidor, $usuario, $pwd);

if(!$link){
    header("location:error_mysql.html"); exit;
}

if(!mysql_select_db($db)) {
    header("location:error_mysql.html"); exit;
}

//buscar todos los registros
$query = "SELECT * FROM paciente ORDER BY ID";
//se guarda el resultado de la query
$resultado = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Error FATAL al buscar datos de $db: " .mysql_error());
$i = 0;
$registros = mysql_num_rows($resultado);

print '{"pacientes": [';
while( $renglon = mysql_fetch_object($resultado)){
    print "{";
    $nombre = $renglon->nombre;
    $apellidos = $renglon->apellidos;
    $edad = $renglon->edad;
    $domicilio = $renglon->domicilio;
    $telefono = $renglon->telefono;
    $email = $renglon->email;
    $dni = $renglon->dni;
    print '"nombre":"'.$nombre.'",';
    print '"apellidos":"'.$apellidos.'",';
    print '"edad":"'.$edad.'",';
    print '"domicilio":"'.$domicilio.'",';
    print '"telefono":"'.$telefono.'",';
    print '"email":"'.$email.'",';
    print '"dni":"'.$dni.'",';
    print "}";
    $i++;
    if($i<$registros){

        print ",";
    }
}
print "]}";
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

y dentro de mi html llamo a mi controlador:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="pacientesApp" ng-controller="controladorPacientes">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="p in pacientes">
                {{p.nombre+", "}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

la cuestion es que cuando lo abro en localhost no me muestra nada, y si lo veo en la consola me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro el fallo.

Comment: Hola alex, ¿podrías incluir el archivo en formato `json`? Es decir, la salida de `pacientesJSON.php`.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es claramente el JSON que esta malformado. No es necesario ni una buena practica realizar este tipo de cosas manualmente cuando php ya inclyue un mecanismo bien probado para hacerlo.

Utilizando [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), pero requiere refactorizar un poco el código:

```
// creamos una lista
$lista = array();

while( $renglon = mysql_fetch_object($resultado)){
    // creamos un registro.
    $r = new stdClass();
    $r->nombre = $renglon->nombre;
    $r->apellidos = $renglon->apellidos;
    $r->edad = $renglon->edad;
    $r->domicilio = $renglon->domicilio;
    $r->telefono = $renglon->telefono;
    $r->email = $renglon->email;
    $r->dni = $renglon->dni;

    // lo agregamos a la lista.
    $lista[] = $r; 
}

// luego generamos un objeto con la pro. pacientes
$response = new stdClass();
$response->pacientes = $lista;

$json = json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

> No encuentro el fallo

El fallo problabemente está que no devuelves un JSON válido desde tu backend. Lo primero que debes hacer es **asegurarte** que devuelva el valor esperado. Es muy importante añadir a nuestras costumbres realizar pruebas periódicamente. Puedes hacerlo con una simple dump o mediante alguna librería de pruebas unitarias.

Dicho esto, hay 2 errores en tu código:

- No establecer el header para JSON
- No envías el JSON mediante `json_encode`

Tu código es poco legible, no esperes entenderlo en unos meses. La forma convencional para enviar un JSON desde PHP es usando `json_encode`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
  $json[] = $row;
}
echo $json_encode($tu_json);
```